# Resizing doesn't correlate with mouse position

Tags: c++, opengl, resize, mouse, glfw

I am using GLFW and when I resize my window it causes the mouse position returned by:

```
int x,y;
glfwGetMousePos(&x,&y);
```

to not correlate with the objects drawn on the screen. Here is what I am using as my resize function:

```
void GLFWResizefunc(int width, int height){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}
```

I first noticed this issue with my buttons, and how they no longer activate on clicking them.

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask, I didn't know what would be needed.

In response to derhass's question:

For buttons I am displaying them with the following:

```
void Button::render() {
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    if(!clicked){
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex);
    }
    else{
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,*pressed);
            }
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (getsx(), getsy());
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f (getSxmax(), getsy());
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (getSxmax(), getSymax());
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f (getsx(), getSymax());
    glEnd();
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    t.render();
}
```

t.render refers to the rendering of the text on the button which is a separate object. Each button has sx, sy, sxmax, and sy max for screen x, y maximum screen x,y. To check if the buttons intersect the mouse click I am passing ints returned through:

```
int x,y;
glfwGetMousePos(&x,&y);
```

to the following function:

```
bool ScreenObject::intersects (float x, float y) {


    std::cout<<"X: "<<x<<"Y: "<<y<<" BX: "<<getsx()<<"BY: "<<getsy()<<std::endl;
    if (x > getsx() && x < getSxmax() ) {
        if (y > getsy() && y < getSymax() )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

if it returns true it intersects the object, in this case a button.

I am using the following:

```
glFrustum (.5, -.5, -.5 * aspect_ratio, .5 * aspect_ratio, 1, 50);
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Well, how do you correlate your mouse coords to the objects you draw? There is a lot of information missing to be able to answer this question.

Comment: A bit. You do never show what matrices and especially projection you use. If you just change the viewport when the window is resized, everything by the GL will be just scaled to fit the new window sice. You might have set up your transformations to match the pixel coords initially, but that might be not the case after the resize if you don't explicitely compensate for this. However, without seeing that code parts, all this is just guesswork...

Comment: Well. not really. Do you really use that perspective projection for drawing the buttons? Your code does suggest that `getsx()` and `getsy()` use pixel coordinates, so you would need either some different `GL_PROJECTION` matrix seup, or some `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix setup you have not yet shown.